# Most efficient way to sort a 2d array with sorted rows into 1d sorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given a 2d array (a matrix) with n rows and k columns, with it's rows sorted, columns unspecified, what would be the most efficient algorithm to sort it?

For exmaple:

```
Input (n = 3 ; k = 4):
1 5 8 10
3 4 5 6
2 3 3 9

Output:
1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 8 9 10
```

This is purely algorithmic question, so no specific .sort() methods of some languages help me, as I'm actually intereseted in the runtime complexity.

What I had in mind would be an algorithm as follows:

```
- Build a Binary Search tree with n nodes. Each node contains:
  ID - of the row it refers to;
  Value - The number at the "head" of the row.
- Sort the tree where the sorting key are the values.
- Find the lowest valued node.
- Do while the tree has a root:
  - Take the lowest value and append it to the new array.
  - Update the node's value to the next one in the same row.
  - If the updated value is null, delete that node.
    - else re-sort the tree.
  - If the node moved, the first node it swapped with will be the next lowest
    - else, if it didn't move, it's the new lowest.
```

If I'm not mistaken the runtime complexity is `O(n*k * log n)`, Since I'm sorting the tree `n*k` times, which takes `O(log n)` time, and process of finding the next lowest is `O(1)`.

If my complexity calculation is wrong, please let me know.

Is there any way more efficient than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have `n` sorted lists, each of size `k`. You need a generalization of [merge-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), which is the k-way merge.

The idea is to keep a [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), that contains the smallest element from each list.

Now, iteratively pop the min of the heap. Let this number be `x`, and say it was taken from row `i`. Now, append `x` to the result list, and add to the min heap the next element in row `i` (if such element exists)

Repeat until all elements are exhausted.

Complexity is `O(n*k*logn)`, which is pretty efficient considering you are sorting `n*k` elements, and need to traverse all of them. The constants for using a binary heap are pretty good.

Note that this is often refered as [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) (or to be exact a close variant to external sort's second part).

This is very similar to the algorithm you are suggesting, but will probably run much faster (with better constants) due to the usage of heap rather than the less efficient tree.

Also note, that if you use a 'regular' binary tree, you get complexity of `O(n^2k)`, since there is no guarantee on the height of the tree. You need a [self balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) in order to get `O(nklogn)` run time.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Sorted Merge which will take o(rows*cols) time i.e. total number of elements and o(rows) space complexity.

The java code for this problem is as below: (Consider rows = 3 and cols = 4)

```
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        index[i] =0;
    }

    int count=0;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c; 

    while(count<(ROWS*COLS))
    {
        int smallest;
        if(index[0]>=COLS)
            a= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else
            a= matrix[0][index[0]];
        if(index[1]>=COLS)
            b = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else
            b = matrix[1][index[1]];
        if(index[2]>=COLS)
            c = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else
            c = matrix[2][index[2]];
        if(a<=b && a<=c){
            // a is smallest
            smallest = a;
            index[0] = index[0] +1;

        }else if(b<=c && b<=a){
            //b is smallest
            smallest = b;
            index[1] = index[1] + 1;
        }else{
            //c is smallest
            smallest = c;
            index[2] = index[2] + 1;
        }
        System.out.print(smallest + ", ");
        count++;
    }
```